# Update list with userform based on multiple criteria in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, list, userform

I have a list with Name, Phone number, City and Dinner.

When the user fills out the user form they type in the abovementioned inputs.

The code updates the list if they fill in the same Name so the list does not append another row. I tried to edit the code such that it take into account Phone number too, but nothing changes.

However, how can I make the list add a new row if the user adds in the same name but different number?

```
Private Sub OKButton_Click()

Dim emptyRow As Long

'Make Sheet1 active
Sheet1.Activate

'Determine emptyRow
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

' try to retrieve the Name
Dim rngIdList As Range, rngId As Range
Dim phoneIdList As Range, phoneId As Range

Set rngIdList = ActiveSheet.Range([a2], [a2].End(xlDown))
Set phoneIdList = ActiveSheet.Range([b2], [b2].End(xlDown))

Set rngId = rngIdList.Find(Me.NameTextBox.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
Set phoneId = phoneIdList.Find(Me.PhoneTextBox.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)

If rngId Is Nothing And phoneId Is Nothing Then
    ' if Name is not found, append new one to the end of the table
    With rngIdList And phoneIdList
        Set rngId = .Offset(.Rows.Count, 0).Resize(1, 1)
        Set phoneId = .Offset(.Rows.Count, 0).Resize(1, 1)
    End With
End If

' update excel record
rngId.Offset(0, 0).Value = Me.NameTextBox.Value
rngId.Offset(0, 1).Value = Me.PhoneTextBox.Value
rngId.Offset(0, 2).Value = Me.CityListBox.Value
rngId.Offset(0, 3).Value = Me.DinnerComboBox.Value

phoneId.Offset(0, 0).Value = Me.NameTextBox.Value
phoneId.Offset(0, 1).Value = Me.PhoneTextBox.Value
phoneId.Offset(0, 2).Value = Me.CityListBox.Value
phoneId.Offset(0, 3).Value = Me.DinnerComboBox.Value
```

Expected output:
Here you can see that Jake adds his name multiple times with different phone numbers, but it doesn't get overwritten (as intended). However, if he adds number 888 again with different Dinner, it will get overwritten with Italian. If he adds number 222, then another row will be added to the list.

[image]

Comment: You are looking for name and phone number in isolation but you need to look in combination. Use autofilter or find and check the offset.

Comment: I tried to use double if conditions `If rngId Is Nothing And phoneId Is Nothing Then` but also add four `phoneId.Offset()`. Didn't work though. Am I on the right track?

Comment: If you want @SJR to respond, don't forget to add the **@** sign infront of there name so that they get the notification when you have added a comment. I would suggest (similar to SJR), use `AutoFilter` for this. Set first filter on the name and then a second one for the phone number. If row is displayed, update the row. If no rows are displayed, add a new row

Comment: For me your code and description seems not to be related with screenshot you posted. Why are you looking for phoneID (using .Find) and why are you setting another range for phoneID?

Comment: @RafałB. The screenshot is what I want my output to be, but I do not get that from my code. I want to change my code such that my table looks like the screenshot.

Comment: So name and number are on the same sheet and in the same row. If yes I would Set one range for name column and use e.g. Application.Match to get position of Me.NameTextBox.Value in our range. If found we use this index (plus constant number of heading rows) to update data in specific row with proper offsets for phone ect. If not found (error) we're adding new row. Clear, simple, without any .Find solution.

Comment: @RafałB. Yes, name and number on same sheet and row! I am not sure how to do this. Can you show me how, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It's untested so let me know how you get on. I've added various explanatory comments.

```
Private Sub OKButton_Click()

Dim emptyRow As Long, s As String, bFound As Boolean

Sheet1.Activate
emptyRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim rngIdList As Range, rngId As Range

Set rngIdList = Range("A2:A" & emptyRow)
Set rngId = rngIdList.Find(Me.NameTextBox.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)

If rngId Is Nothing Then 'NAME NOT FOUND SO ADD NEW RECORD
    With Range("A" & emptyRow + 1)
        .Value = Me.NameTextBox.Value
        .Offset(0, 1).Value = Me.PhoneTextBox.Value
        .Offset(0, 2).Value = Me.CityListBox.Value
        .Offset(0, 3).Value = Me.DinnerComboBox.Value
    End With
Else 'NAME FOUND
    s = rngId.Address
    Do
        If rngId.Offset(, 1).Value = Me.PhoneTextBox.Value Then 'PHONE NUMBER FOUND FOR SAME NAME SO UPDATE RECORD
            With rngId
                .Offset(0, 2).Value = Me.CityListBox.Value
                .Offset(0, 3).Value = Me.DinnerComboBox.Value
            End With
            bFound = True
            Exit Do 'NO NEED TO KEEP LOOKING
        End If
        Set rngId = rngIdList.FindNext(rngId)
    Loop While rngId.Address <> s 'KEEP LOOKING UNTIL BACK TO FIRST FOUND VALUE
    If Not bFound Then 'IF NAME/PHONE COMBO HAS NOT BEEN FOUND
        With Range("A" & emptyRow + 1)
            .Value = Me.NameTextBox.Value
            .Offset(0, 1).Value = Me.PhoneTextBox.Value
            .Offset(0, 2).Value = Me.CityListBox.Value
            .Offset(0, 3).Value = Me.DinnerComboBox.Value
        End With
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, but this code does exactly like RafalB in the sense that only a new row gets added regardless of the Name or Phone already exists or not. But the code works as intended if I put in text instead of numbers for phone numbers!

Comment: I would suggest specifying all Find parameters.

Comment: You might also have to convert the text box value to a number

Answer (score 1):

So many variables to make it easier to understand to you. Something like this (not tested, i didn't build userform)

```
Dim enteredName As String
    enteredName = Me.NameTextBox.Value

Dim headerRow As Long
    headerRow = 1 ' row containing headers

Dim lastDataRow As Long
    lastDataRow = sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim namesRng As Range
Set namesRng = sheet1.Range("A" & headerRow + 1 & ":A" & lastDataRow)

Dim position As Variant
    ' dim as Variant because if value not found by Match
    ' instead of Long we'll receive error
    position = Application.Match(enteredName, namesRng, False)

Dim dataRow As Long ' row we'll add or update

    If IsError(position) Then
        dataRow = lastDataRow + 1 ' case: adding new row
    Else
        dataRow = position + headerRow ' case updating existing row
    End If

With sheet1.Range("A" & dataRow)
    .Value = enteredName ' not necessary when updating row, but maybe easier to read
    .Offset(0, 1).Value = Me.PhoneTextBox.Value
    .Offset(0, 2).Value = Me.CityListBox.Value
    .Offset(0, 3).Value = Me.DinnerComboBox.Value
End With
```

Comment: I may understand something, but your code does the same thing as mine. Was that your intention?

Comment: OK, I just get what you want to achieve. Your case probably would be simplified by checking only phoneID instead name. What do you think?

Comment: Is it possible to check both name and phoneid instead of just one of them? Because I want to check if name is the same but phoneid is different, then add new row. if name and phoneid is the same, then update the same row.